# setting up monodevelop in xfce

Tags: mono, ubuntu-16.04, monodevelop, gnome-terminal, xfce

I use this solution to have a VNC desktop session with a remote Ubuntu PC https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04

I want to setup monodevelop on this machine. I followed the instructions and am able to run monodevelop and write code, however when I attempt to run it I get "Could not connect to the debugger". I tried various solutions suggesting changing environment variables to force monodevelop to use xterm and it did not work, however I'm not positive I did it correctly as the solution was meant for gnome and the modifications to the command for XFCE were not clear to me. At this point I'd be willing to get paid support, but I'm not even sure where I could find any for my use case. Does anyone have experience getting monodevelop to work on XFCE? If not what is the best environment for getting it going (ideally a way where I could remote in too). I'm very accustomed to the RDP workflow where I can actually troubleshoot on a development server and be very close to the real world environment to get things running, then check-in and deploy. I think there are a lot of platform differences with monodevelop so I really really really want to develop on Ubuntu (remotely).

Comment: "I tried various solutions"? What exactly did you try? And also what version of MonoDevelop do you use?

Comment: the latest build as of 2019-02-04